# Best practices for managing versions between backend and frontend

Tags: version-control, frontend, version, backend, project

I'm posting my question because I haven't found clear answers to what I've read so far.
I have an application made up of a backend, a frontend (angular) and a mobile application.
Currently each project has its own versioning, is this a good practice or should we align all the technologies to one version?
We often find ourselves in the case where we make a feature that will impact the backend and mobile but not the frontend, in this case we do not increase the version number of the frontend (because no dev on this part). Version gaps appear, but the client has difficulty understanding this and often management insists that we also increase the frontend version so that all versions are aligned.
I think this is an aberration because for me versioning should reflect a technical reality and not be a reflection of what is best to present a new application delivery.